# split a column of string in several columns

Tags: r, dataframe, strsplit

I have the data frame

```
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(8),y=runif(8),longstring=c("foo_100_Case1","foo_125_Case1","bar_100_Case1","bar_125_Case1","foo_100_Case2","foo_125_Case2","bar_100_Case2","bar_125_Case2"),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I need to split the last column in three columns, with delimiter "_". I've been doing the following:

```
a=matrix(unlist(strsplit(df$longstring,"_",fixed=T)),8,3,byrow = T)
df$type=a[,1]
df$point=a[,2]
df$case=a[,3]
```

But I wonder if there's an easier way: the combination of `strsplit`and `unlist` is particularly awkward, and it doesn't make the code very readable.

Comment: The function `separate` in the package **tidyr** was specifically written for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try,

```
cbind(df[-3], data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(df$longstring,'_'))))

#    x               y   X1  X2    X3
#1 -0.5522704 0.9998266 foo 100 Case1
#2  1.1907351 0.8979460 foo 125 Case1
#3  0.6005691 0.4301610 bar 100 Case1
#4 -1.0698081 0.9626781 bar 125 Case1
#5 -0.8526932 0.9634738 foo 100 Case2
#6  0.0100209 0.2968137 foo 125 Case2
#7 -1.5051358 0.7012956 bar 100 Case2
#8  1.0892584 0.4655736 bar 125 Case2
```

The `do.call` function allows you to call any R function and instead of sending the argument one by one you can use a list to hold the arguments. More info `?do.call`. The `do.call` returns only `X1`, `X2` and `X3` columns and to get your original data frame i am using `cbind` to bind the original columns. The `strsplit` as you already know splits the string across `_`.

---

Or as @joran mentioned you can use `separate` from `tidyr` package like

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, longstring, c("X1", "X2", "X3"), sep="_")

#    x               y   X1  X2    X3
#1 -0.5522704 0.9998266 foo 100 Case1
#2  1.1907351 0.8979460 foo 125 Case1
#3  0.6005691 0.4301610 bar 100 Case1
#4 -1.0698081 0.9626781 bar 125 Case1
#5 -0.8526932 0.9634738 foo 100 Case2
#6  0.0100209 0.2968137 foo 125 Case2
#7 -1.5051358 0.7012956 bar 100 Case2
#8  1.0892584 0.4655736 bar 125 Case2
```

Comment: Definitely more readable than mine, and I like that you drop `df$longstring`. Can you please explain your code, though? What's `do.call`? Why do you  need both `cbind` and `rbind`? Why in your code do you need `as.character`, while in mine I can directly write `strsplit(df$longstring...)`?

Comment: Ok, I like the `tidyr` syntax best. Usually I don't like to install packages to do stuff which can be done in base R will do, but I really like the fact that `tidyr` allows me to separate and rename columns in one go. And the syntax is much more readable!

Comment: @DeltaIV you are right, `tidyr` is more readable and also there is no need for `as.character` in `strsplit`, hence updated

Answer (score 7):

Here are some more options to try:

***My "splitstackshape" package is designed for this kind of stuff...***

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "longstring", "_")
#              x         y longstring_1 longstring_2 longstring_3
# 1: -1.41524742 0.2123978          foo          100        Case1
# 2: -1.09240237 0.3899935          foo          125        Case1
# 3:  0.39675025 0.2162463          bar          100        Case1
# 4: -1.14996728 0.7608128          bar          125        Case1
# 5: -0.07657172 0.6878348          foo          100        Case2
# 6:  0.29549599 0.2216566          foo          125        Case2
# 7:  1.78622612 0.1496666          bar          100        Case2
# 8: -0.11749579 0.9255409          bar          125        Case2
```

***The "data.table" package brings us the fast `tstrsplit` function...***

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[
  , paste0("V", 1:3) := tstrsplit(longstring, "_")][
    , longstring := NULL][]
```

***If you have the time and want to wait for `read.table` to do its work...***

```
cbind(df[1:2], read.table(text = df$longstring, sep = "_"))
```

***If you need something else that is fast...***

```
library(iotools)
cbind(df[1:2], mstrsplit(df$longstring, sep = "_"))
```